# Host doesn't recognize my psr-4 class on composer

Tags: php

I created a page for tests using easyphp, in easyphp the classes are loaded normally and everything works fine, but when sending the files to the hosting, the classes are no longer recognized for some reason I don't know... does anyone know how to help me?

Page: https://spetests.000webhostapp.com/gerar-qrcode-dinamico.php

```bash
Error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'App\Pix\Api' not found in /storage/ssd4/870/19749870/public_html/gerar-qrcode-dinamico.php:12 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /storage/ssd4/870/19749870/public_html/gerar-qrcode-dinamico.php on line 12
```

Files(from tutorial): https://github.com/william-costa/wdev-qrcode-pix-php

Comment: Share any errors you see, including logs in your question. Also share the actual code you wrote.

Comment: sorry, I'm not used to posting errors here, but I fixed the problem, I put the error and the files that were made available in the tutorial I followed

Comment: (I fixed the post error...)